# Best Design approach for multi-shape graph nodes drawing

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I am using Qt C++ to draw graph which represents an electronic circuit. The problem is that not all nodes have the same shape ,I have 2 kinds of nodes(circle, polygon) ,there is an edge class and a node class to draw graphs.The problem is that they are tightly coupled,for each node I have to define the bounding rectangle that it must be drawn inside it,and I use the bounding rectangle dimensions in the edge object connecting 2 nodes.for example here is a bounding rectangle for a rectangular node:

```
    QRectF Node::boundingRect() const {
        qreal cx=-22;
        qreal cy=-11;
        return QRect(cx,cy,-2*cx,-2*cy);
    }
```

And here is how the edge get drawn for each node

```
     void Edge::adjust(){
         if(!sourceNode || !destNode)
         return;

         QLineF line(mapFromItem(this->sourceNode,0,0),mapFromItem(this->destNode, 0, 0));
         qreal length=line.length();
         qreal rx=22; //radius of Node bounding rectangle in x direction
         qreal ry=11; //radius of Node bounding rectangle in y direction

         prepareGeometryChange();

        if(length>20){
            QPointF offset((line.dx() * rx)/length,(line.dy()*ry)/length);
            //adjusting the start position of edges
            sourcePoint=line.p1() + offset;
            destPoint=line.p2() - offset;
        }
        else{
            sourcePoint=destPoint=line.p1();
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to use these 2 classes to work with different type of nodes. I thought of inheriting from node class and override the bounding rectangle function for each different shape, but I don't know how to draw edges for different types of nodes.
To sum it up,I want to know what's the best practice to draw a graph with 2 shapes of nodes ,given that to draw the edges I have to know the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of each node.